# Loading Bloomberg Api Data Using VBA Access Program

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ms-access, bloomberg

we have subscription to Bloomberg data,
we use excel to load data from bloomberg using bdp function.
but its pain,so we decided to find easy way to do this .
Is there any way to program and calculate Fixed Income Chars from a list of securities using VBA ,access,sql or anything.?

Thanks

Comment: You might get better help if you ask a more specific question. What aspect of the solution are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an old question, but maybe one will look for an answer. Basically you can retrieve the same data via Bloomberg API. For the personal use it is a Desktop API (currently version 3). The Quick Start Guide (can be downloaded from Bloomberg Terminal) provides examples for C++, Java and C#. The names of the fields are exactly the same as in the bdp function. For example:

```
Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");
fields.AppendValue("PX_LAST");
fields.AppendValue("VOLUME_AVG_30D");
session.SendRequest(request,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to use either VBA automation to do this in excel, or write directly to the c api.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Excel VBA already then it will be quite easy to copy and paste the code into Access VBA.   You will then need to make appropriate changes to insert records rather than inserting cells.   If using DAO you will want to use code similar to the following to add the records.

```
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Customer")
    rs.AddNew
    rs!cName = NewData
    rs.Update
    rs.Move 0, rs.LastModified
    CustomerID = rs!cID
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
```

The rs.move 0 line fetches the autonumbr key of the record just added should you need it to insert child records.